# functions logic doesn't make sense for javascript clock app

Tags: javascript

```js
function showTime () {

 let date = new Date();
 let hours = date.getHours(); //0-23
 let minutes = date.getMinutes(); //0-59
 let seconds = date.getSeconds(); //0-59

 let formatHours = convertFormat(hours);

 hours = checkTime(hours);

 hours = addZero(hours);
 minutes = addZero(minutes);
 seconds = addZero(seconds);
 document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + formatHours;

 }

 function convertFormat(time) {
  let format = 'AM';
  if (time >= 12) {
   format = 'PM';
  }
  return format;
 }

 function checkTime(time) {
  if (time > 12) {
   time = time - 12;
  }
  if (time === 0) {
   time = 12;
  }
  return time;
 }

 function addZero(time) {
  if (time < 10) {
   time = "0" + time;
  }
  return time;
 }

showTime();
setInterval(showTime, 1000);
```

```css
body {
 min-height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: center;
 background-color: black;

}

#clock {
 font-family: 'Orbitron';
 font-size: 5rem;
 color: limegreen;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Clocck</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <div id="clock">
  
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hey guys I'm currently working on a simple clock app. There's a particular function that doesn't make much sense to me. The convertFormat function's if statement sets up time to equal 'PM' if it is >= 12. Well the reverse is happening to me. Its reading 8:33pm? when it checks the hours variable and reads 8 it should switch format to am? right?

Comment: I'm getting the right time.
I don't know which time is in your timezone right now... it should show 8.33pm if it is 8 in the evening or 8.33am if it is in the morning

Comment: You've done the `convertFormat` before changing it to 12-Hours format so the logic is fine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, it makes sense. The function displays the time in 12 hour format so even though its 8:33 but in the evening, it will show as 8:33 pm. If you want to see 8:33 as AM only and 20:33 as PM, change the function to use 24 hr format

Comment: This doesn't answer the question:  Why is the convertFormat function returning PM when 8 < 12 ?

Comment: If you check the code AM PM is determined before 12 is subtracted from the number of hours. So if its PM, the value of hours is 20 when time format is determined. 12 is subtracted later

Answer (score 0):

The reason that when you see the time is 8:33PM, it still display PM instead of AM because the date.getHours() function will return your "system clock", not the clock value display by your function. It mean that when you mistakenly think the input variable for your convertFormat function is "8", it is actually 20 in your system clock.